# Which year in the future did John Connor and Catherine Weaver go to?

Tags: terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In the final episode of *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles* season 2 ***(Born to Run)***, John Henry took Cameron's chip and went to the future. After that Catherine Weaver and John Connor use a time machine in the basement of Catherine Weaver's building, going to the future and looking for John Henry and Cameron's chip.

[image]

When they came to the future no one knows who John Connor is. So does anyone know which year in the future John Connor and Catherine Weaver traveled to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this the right answer or there's a proof for it but I assume it's the same time they were originally got sent back from, which is 2027 and in this time line, Alison still alive and no one know John

Here's Derek [wikia](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Derek_Reese), he was born in 1995 and he's 32 years old, which means that he was sent back from 2027.

and from Alison [wikia](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Allison_Young#Alternative_timeline)

> Following the deactivation of Cameron at the hands of John Henry, John Connor and Catherine Weaver jumped to 2027. However, this was an alternate timeline where John Connor never became leader of the Resistance. There they found Allison Young alive and well with Derek and Kyle Rees.

Edit : OK, That was not really correct. From [this](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_222:_Born_to_Run#Time_travel)

> Q: What year did John Connor and Catherine Weaver jump to?
>
> A: **Unknown.** There was no display indicating the destined time period in John Henry's chamber, only a countdown clock. There is no official date given for their arrival in the episode; however, it could be assumed that it is either 2026 or 2027 by the ages of Kyle and Derek. We know only that it is sometime after Judgment Day. It could be, or may not be, before John Connor takes control over the Resistance. In this new timeline, it is possible John may not have existed (which is likely due to the transport as no one would have grown up to become John Connor).

Comment: thank you so much for your answer..but their are some facts i like to talk about.. starting like this..in The Sarah Connor Chronicles season 1 in 1st Episode Sara asking from Cameron "witch year are you from" Cameron replies 2027, in that time Cameron very close to John Connor (may be in a relation ship) & he send her to the past to protect young John Connor.  in 2027 John was Establish as the leader of the resistant. so i think John Connor and Catherine Weaver cam to a year before 2027

Comment: @RANSARA009 Yeah, but when john traveled  to the future (in the last episode), that changed everything. He didn't exist in the world anymore and he didn't live through judgment day so he didn't join then lead the resistant, (Hence no one knows him or even heard his name before). The other thing that changed is that Alison still alive so Cameron also don't exit.